# How to create an instance of IDiaDataSource when using the #import command?

Tags: c++, com

I'm trying use the `#import` command on `msdia140.dll` which is for the [Debug Interface Access SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6tay6cz.aspx).

Yes, I know that there is a header file for it already with the interfaces, but I want to use smart COM pointers, hence the use of the `#import` command.

The import command I use is:

```
#import "bin/msdia140.dll" \
    rename("virtual", "Virtual")\
    exclude(               \
      "IStream"            \
    , "ISequentialStream"  \
    , "_LARGE_INTEGER"     \
    , "_ULARGE_INTEGER"    \
    , "tagSTATSTG"         \
    , "_FILETIME"          \
    , "IEnumUnknown")
```

The rename is because of a keyword conflict, and the exclusions are to get rid of warnings of importing types whose names already exist.

In the `...App::InitInstance()` function, I call `CoInitialize(NULL);` and in the `...App::ExitInstance()` I have `CoUninitialize();`.

Now I'm trying to do the equivalent to:

```
CComPtr<IDiaDataSource> pSource;
CoCreateInstance( CLSID_DiaSource,
                   NULL,
                   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                   __uuidof( IDiaDataSource ),
                  (void **) &pSource);
```

in as stated in the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eee38t3h.aspx), but without success.  The command I've tried is:

```
Dia2Lib::IDiaDataSourcePtr dataSource;
dataSource.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Dia2Lib::IDiaDataSource));
```

but the smart pointer remains as `NULL`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the return value of CreateInstance().  It will tell you the problem, or at least the first problem.

One problem I see off the bat is this:

```
Dia2Lib::IDiaDataSourcePtr dataSource;
dataSource.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Dia2Lib::IDiaDataSource));
```

It should be:

```
Dia2Lib::IDiaDataSourcePtr dataSource;
HRESULT hr = dataSource.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Dia2Lib::DiaSource));
```

You are using an interface ID instead of the CLSID of a coclass--will always be a problem.

Comment: I had thought of using a `CLSID_*` variable before, but there were no `CLSID_*` variables defined.

Comment: Well, you need to use a CLSID.  It might not be called CLSID_*.... Just find out which one is the coclass.  Then something like __uuidof(Dia2Lib::DiaDataSource) or something.  If you have the path to the DLL, use oleview to view it... oleview c:\path\to\msdia140.dll.  From there you can look at the typelibrary and find the coclass objects.

Comment: For grins, I searched on my computer and found msdia120.dll.  The coclasses are DiaSource, DiaSourceAlt, and DiaStackWalker.  Using __uuidof(Dia2Lib::DiaSource) will probably work.

Comment: Ok, that works. Update your answer and I'll mark it as done.